# reset Ethernet bonding without rebooting

Tags: networking, ethernet, bonding

I have the following Ethernet bonding configuration:

old configuration:

```
bond0
  eth0
  eth1
bond1
  eth2
  eth3
```

new configuration :

```
bond0
  eth0
  eth2
bond1
  eth1
  eth3
```

I have made the change and restart `service network restart` but `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0` and `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond1` still shows the old configuration. I had to reboot the system to be able to see the new configuration. Is there a way to do this without reboot?

I am using RHEL6.5

Comment: You haven't mentioned what distribution are you running.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make any changes to the config files which do not reflect the current state of the system, otherwise the network scripts get confused when they read the config to stop networking, but the config files don't match what's actually configured.

The correct way to change network config files is first stop networking (`service network stop`), *then* make your config file changes, then start networking again (`service network start`).

Stopping the network service will remove network access, so make sure you're using out-of-band access (ILO, DRAC, etc) and not SSH or other network-based access.

Comment: I have the same question for Ubuntu 18.04. There is no service named `network` there and it uses Netplan. I tried `netplan apply` and restarting `systemd-networkd` but those are not enough to change parameters like mii-monitor-interval or mode.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your all eth configurationg files are correct. Post that if you want to change the slave use "ifenslave" command

Syntax

ifenslave -d bood0

to Attach a device

ifenslave bond0